# How do combo boxes, when displaying list items, intercept mouse events to anywhere on the form to hide the list?

Tags: .net, winforms, events, combobox

I'm trying to implement a .net form control with functionality similar to a combo box, but I don't know the proper method to intercept mouse events anywhere on the form to un-expand the list of items.

How do I prevent other controls from responding to mouse events while the list is being shown?

How do I efficiently and safely catch a mouse click event to anywhere on the form, to hide the expanded list?

Comment: you can find another solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15305176/1522062

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a `ToolStripControlHost` along with the `ToolStripDropDown`, and it will work just like the `ComboBox` dropdown.  You won't have to worry about handling the mouse events.

I've used this before:

```
Private Sub ShowControl(ByVal fromControl As Control, ByVal whichControl As Control)
  '\\ whichControl needs MinimumSize set:'
  whichControl.MinimumSize = whichControl.Size

  Dim toolDrop As New ToolStripDropDown()
  Dim toolHost As New ToolStripControlHost(whichControl)
  toolHost.Margin = New Padding(0)
  toolDrop.Padding = New Padding(0)
  toolDrop.Items.Add(toolHost)
  toolDrop.Show(Me, New Point(fromControl.Left, fromControl.Bottom))
End Sub
```

Quick Demo with a Button control on a form:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  ShowControl(Button1, New MonthCalendar)
End Sub
```

To answer the question in your title, I *think* the pinvoke calls of [SetCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Release Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are used to handle that type of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[Control.Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture.aspx)

As explained in the documentation, you now "Own" the mouse (until someone else captures it - though that's bad form).  You receive all mouse messages and can handle a "Down" not on your control to dismiss.

Comment: This only seems to half work. All of the controls within the control with mouse capture stop working. For example, the scroll bar within a list box with mouse capture doesn't work until capture is released.