# How to simulate a drop-down window in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

i know a Windows `Combobox` control is nothing but [a `Textbox` and a `ListBox`glued together](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/10/548537.aspx).

i need to simulate the same thing in WinForms. i am trying to figure out Windows window options that must be set to achieve the proper effect.

- the drop-down cannot be a [*child window*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#child) - otherwise it is clipped to the parent's area
- conceptually it must be a [*pop-up window*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#popup) - an overlapped window
- it can be an [owned window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#owned_windows) - An owned window is always above its owner in the z-order. The system automatically destroys an owned window when its owner is destroyed. An owned window is hidden when its owner is minimized.

The best i've managed so far is to create

- a borderless (`this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None`)
- topmost (`this.TopMost = true`)
- form that doesn't show in the taskbar (`this.ShowInTaskbar = false`)

this borderless topmost form contains my "drop-down" control. i "hide" my dropdown when the dropdown form loses focus:

```
this.Deactivate += new EventHandler(TheDropDownForm_Deactivate);

void TheDropDownForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...

   this.Close();
}
```

This conglomeration of mess works well enough...

[image]

...except that "drop-down" takes focus away from the owner form.

And this is my question, what properties should my popup window have?

- [SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus-in-c)?

But then how do i hide my drop-down form when it loses focus - **when it cannot lose focus**?

---

How do i simulate a combo-box drop-down in .NET?

---

**Note:** Don't confuse what you see in the example screenshot with something else. i am asking how to create "drop-down" form in Winforms - the contents can be different than the screenshot above:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a C# Winforms Control that hovers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353561/how-to-create-a-c-sharp-winforms-control-that-hovers)

Comment: I am curious as to where / how / why you would need something like this?  You may want to consider using a WPF control (much easier to manipulate and you can use with WinForms).

Comment: @HansPassant Fundamentally that answer can't serve me, because the control is "parented". And if parented then it will clip to it's parent (i.e. the "drop-down" can exist outside of its "parent" form)

Comment: you can find another solution here: [stackoverflow.com/a/15305176/1522062](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15305176/1522062)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `ToolStripControlHost` and a `ToolStripDropDown` can achieve the same effect.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8611382/719186):

```
Private Sub ShowControl(ByVal fromControl As Control, ByVal whichControl As Control)
  '\\ whichControl needs MinimumSize set:'
  whichControl.MinimumSize = whichControl.Size

  Dim toolDrop As New ToolStripDropDown()
  Dim toolHost As New ToolStripControlHost(whichControl)
  toolHost.Margin = New Padding(0)
  toolDrop.Padding = New Padding(0)
  toolDrop.Items.Add(toolHost)
  toolDrop.Show(Me, New Point(fromControl.Left, fromControl.Bottom))
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems reasonable, except for `toolDrop.Show` throws *Top-level control cannot be added to a control.*. Presumably because i am trying to show a `Form`.

Comment: @IanBoyd True, but then just make `TopLevel = false;`

Comment: Excellent with the `TopLevel`, i had no idea that existed (or how it differs from `TopMost`). Bonus: it even has the "popup shadow". The only thing left is how do i know when the "popup" is closed? Neither the `Deactivate` or `FormClosed` event fire.

Comment: @IanBoyd Look at the ToolStripDropDown events.  You will have `Opened`, `Opening`, `Closed` and `Closing` events you can wire up.

Comment: Thanks, Lars - i think there's enough information here to solve the drop-down answer. It's going to take a bit of work so i can sort out the jumbled hodge-podge mess to the point where's a good enough-generic answer for the other generic "popup" question. Right now all the code intertwined.